# Slow loading of page javascript

Tags: javascript, html, performance, optimization

I have this javascript code.

```js
<!-- //////////////////// IMAGE 1 //////////////////// -->
var i = 1;
var Imgt2e10 = Array.apply(null, new Array(10)).map(function() { 
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "img/t2/t2e10/"+(i++)+".jpg"
  return img
});

function RollOvert2e10(i) { 
  document.t2e10.src=Imgt2e10[i].src; 
}

<!-- //////////////////// IMAGE 2 //////////////////// -->
var i = 1;
var Imgt2e2 = Array.apply(null, new Array(10)).map(function() { 
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "img/t2/t2e2/"+(i++)+".jpg"
  return img
});

function RollOvert2e2(i) { 
  document.t2e2.src=Imgt2e2[i].src; 
}

<!-- //////////////////// IMAGE 3 //////////////////// -->
var i = 1;
var Imgt2e3 = Array.apply(null, new Array(10)).map(function() { 
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "img/t2/t2e3/"+(i++)+".jpg"
  return img
});

function RollOvert2e3(i) { 
  document.t2e3.src=Imgt2e3[i].src; 
}
```

Each of these bits of code applies to one image. In this example I have 3 images but in my website I have more than 50 and it's taking too long to load the web page.

Is it because I'm repeating the code over and over or because I have too many images (small jpg's) loading at the same time?

How can I make this code shorter and elegant? Or at least the loading faster...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's 30 images you're trying to load... Not 3. In a very strange way too.

Comment: Clearly it's the loading that takes time. JavaScript execution time is only a few milliseconds in all. Have you checked the size of all these JPEGs? You might want to compress them a bit more.

Comment: @Rudie Yes... For each image I'm displaying ten more on hover (I used image map for that). Is the amount of images the problem?

Comment: Thank you @kuroineko. I will try to compress them more. I still feel like all this javascript code repetition is unnecessary...

Comment: Indeed you could improve the JavaScript bit, but this is likely not the cause of the slowdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed previously, the slowdown is most certainly caused by the size of the images. Now for some less cumbersome JS code, I would propose something like that:

```
function Loader (basename)
{
    this.image = {};
    this.basename = basename;
}

Loader.prototype = {
    load: function (name)
    {
        this.image[name] = new array(10);
        for (var i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++)
        {
            this.images[name][i] = new Image ();
            this.images[name][i].src = "img/"+basename+"/"+name+"/"+i+".jpg";
        }
    },

    rollover: function (name, index)
    {
        document[name].src = image[name][index].src;
    }
}


var loader = new Loader("t2"); // create a loader for the t2 folder

loader.load ("whatever"); // load an image collection
loader.rollover ("whatever", 5); // roll over to the 5th image
```